# please help me in recovering my lost contacts on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Please I formatted my phone by mistake and in the process my WhatsApp was uninstalled and some very important contacts deleted please how can I still get the contacts back on WhatsApp please help.

Answer (score 0):

The contacts would be safe if you have saved them either in your SIM or have backed up them in your Google Account. The main thing is whether you have a chat backup or not. If not, then I don't think there's any way you can get the chat back on your phone. If it is there (assuming that you have not deleted that backup) then you will get a prompt to install it when you are again logging in with your number.
A same instance happened with me and luckily I had a backup in My Drive account.